# Where can I obtain the mdns.service file needed for building mDNS in Yocto?

Tags: linux, yocto, mdns, nxp-microcontroller

This question follows on from:
[How does one get everything right to build mDNS in Yocto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268257/how-does-one-get-everything-right-to-build-mdns-in-yocto/)
Looking at this recipe,
http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-networking/recipes-protocols/mdns/mdns_878.200.35.bb?h=zeus
Seems to be the same as:
https://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-networking/recipes-protocols/mdns/mdns_878.200.35.bb?h=zeus
one of the files required in the SRC_URI is mdns.service . Where can I obtain this file?
It is not linked from
https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/109743/
as the two patches are.

Best regards,
...
The saga continues: [Do I need to edit the .patch files needed for building mdns 878.200.35 in Yocto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66400231/do-i-need-to-edit-the-patch-files-needed-for-building-mdns-878-200-35-in-yocto)

Comment: http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-networking/recipes-protocols/mdns/files/mdns.service?h=zeus

Comment: Thanks @OleksandrKravchuk ; I'll take a look.