# How do I strip and objcopy a built .so file in the Yocto bitbake compile step?

Tags: yocto, stackexchange-api, nxp-microcontroller

This question follows on from:
[Do I need to edit the .patch files needed for building mdns 878.200.35 in Yocto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66400231/do-i-need-to-edit-the-patch-files-needed-for-building-mdns-878-200-35-in-yocto/)
This chains back through several posts to considerable background.

Since "mDNS" seemed to be working in my target and the recipe puts libdns_sd.so in
"/usr/bin/", I went on to the next need, which is to build OCA, which links with
libdns_sd.so. I created another layer for it and copied in my source files, in a
folder called "Src", to an oca-1.2.7 folder under the files folder in my layer.
I wrote the following recipe for it. The CAP_HOME environment variable has to be
set to the base folder, oca-1.2.7, for "makefileOCA", etc., to work.
Putting underlined text in quotes seems to help get StackOverflow to accept my question formatting.
Also I put // comment markers in front of every line in my code or output blocks. Not sure if that helped.

```
//DESCRIPTION = "OCA"  
//PRIORITY = "optional"  
//SECTION = "protocols"  
//LICENSE = "MIT"  
//LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"  
//SRC_URI = "file://oca-1.2.7"  
//S = "${WORKDIR}/oca-1.2.7/Src"  
//# Need to override S because BitBake expects the source to be in a dir called  
//#  oca-1.2.7 in the work dir, but it's actually additionally under Src/.  
//# Need a do_compile, since OCA has a makefile with a non-standard name,  
//# makefileOCA. Also needs non-standard flags, -f and linuxRelease.  
//do_compile() {  
//export CAP_HOME="${WORKDIR}/oca-1.2.7"  
//make -f makefileOCA linuxRelease  
//}  
//do_install() {  
//    install -d ${D}${libdir}  
//    cp ../Obj/linuxApp/Release/OcaProtoController.so ${D}${libdir}/OcaProtoController.so  
//    chmod 0755 ${D}${libdir}/OcaProtoController.so  
//}
```

Then I "bitbaked" or compiled my new layer:

```
//~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland$ time bitbake oca  
//[Text is in white starting with the preceeding "time bitbake oca"]  
//Parsing recipes: 100% |############################################################################################| Time: 0:01:04  
//Parsing of 3212 .bb files complete (0 cached, 3212 parsed). 4627 targets, 468 skipped, 1 masked, 0 errors.  
//NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies  

//Build Configuration:  
//BB_VERSION           = "1.44.0"  
//BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"  
//NATIVELSBSTRING      = "ubuntu-18.04"  
//TARGET_SYS           = "aarch64-poky-linux"  
//MACHINE              = "imx8mnddr4evk"  
//DISTRO               = "fsl-imx-wayland"  
//DISTRO_VERSION       = "5.4-zeus"  
//TUNE_FEATURES        = "aarch64 cortexa53 crc crypto"  
//TARGET_FPU           = ""  
//(snip SHA IDs)  

//Initialising tasks: 100% |#########################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01  
//Sstate summary: Wanted 13 Found 7 Missed 6 Current 67 (53% match, 92% complete)  
//NOTE: Executing Tasks  
//NOTE: Setscene tasks completed  
//[Following text is all in red]  
//ERROR: oca-1.2.7-r0 do_populate_sysroot: Fatal errors occurred in subprocesses:  
//Command '['aarch64-poky-linux-strip', '--remove-section=.comment', '--remove-section=.note', '--strip-unneeded', '~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/oca/1.2.7-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/OcaProtoController.so']' returned non-zero exit status 1.  
//Subprocess output:aarch64-poky-linux-strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/oca/1.2.7-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/OcaProtoController.so'  

//ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: ~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/oca/1.2.7-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sysroot.14772  
//ERROR: Task (~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland/meta-oca-so/recipes-example/oca/oca_1.2.7.bb:do_populate_sysroot) failed with exit code '1'  
//ERROR: oca-1.2.7-r0 do_package: Fatal errors occurred in subprocesses:  
//Command '['aarch64-poky-linux-objcopy', '--only-keep-debug', '~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/oca/1.2.7-r0/package/usr/lib/OcaProtoController.so', '~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/oca/1.2.7-r0/package/usr/lib/.debug/OcaProtoController.so']' returned non-zero exit status 1.  
//Subprocess output:aarch64-poky-linux-objcopy: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/oca/1.2.7-r0/package/usr/lib/OcaProtoController.so'  

//ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: ~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/oca/1.2.7-r0/temp/log.do_package.14771  
//ERROR: Task (~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland/meta-oca-so/recipes-example/oca/oca_1.2.7.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'  
//[Above text is all in red; back to white text following]  
//NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 504 tasks of which 494 didn't need to be rerun and 2 failed.  

//Summary: 2 tasks failed:  
  //~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland/meta-oca-so/recipes-example/oca/oca_1.2.7.bb:do_populate_sysroot  
  //~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland/meta-oca-so/recipes-example/oca/oca_1.2.7.bb:do_package  
//Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.  

//real    5m36.431s  
//user    0m0.344s  
//sys     0m0.057s
```

I found:

```
//~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland$ find -iname *OcaProtoController*  
//./tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/oca/1.2.7-r0/oca-1.2.7/Obj/linuxApp/Release/OcaProtoController.so  
//./tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/oca/1.2.7-r0/image/usr/lib/OcaProtoController.so  
//./tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/oca/1.2.7-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/OcaProtoController.so  
//./tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/oca/1.2.7-r0/package/usr/lib/OcaProtoController.so
```

This is extremely encouraging. I am getting my build result,
OcaProtoController.so, and now I just need to get it through the indicated strip
and "objcopy" operations, or "do_populate_sysroot" and "do_package", which appear to
be the respective tasks.

So how do I fix this? Additionally, can you point me to the best relevant
documentation so that I can understand the fundamental processes? Meanwhile I
continue to google and read.

Edit: I'm kind of hoping for an answer that would obviate the following horrible hack. But whatever works, I guess.

I found and tried this: https://github.com/nefethael/meta-random/issues/1 :

```
//It compiles if you do the most horrible hack ever.  
//INHIBIT_SYSROOT_STRIP = "1"  
//INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"  
//INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT = "1"  
//The file stats is an executable file hidden in the vendor reference.
```

I put those three lines in ~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland/conf/local.conf under CONF_VERSION = "1". That clearly had an effect:
It seemed to go over almost every other package, taking about 20 mins:

```
//~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland$ time bitbake oca  
//Parsing recipes: 100% |############################################################################################| Time: 0:01:04  
//Parsing of 3212 .bb files complete (0 cached, 3212 parsed). 4627 targets, 468 skipped, 1 masked, 0 errors.  
//NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies  

//Build Configuration:  
//(snip)  
//Initialising tasks: 100% |#########################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00  
//Sstate summary: Wanted 80 Found 0 Missed 80 Current 0 (0% match, 0% complete)  
//NOTE: Executing Tasks  
//NOTE: Setscene tasks completed  
//[Following text is all in red]  
//ERROR: oca-1.2.7-r0 do_package: QA Issue: oca: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:  
  // /usr  
  // /usr/lib  
  // /usr/lib/OcaProtoController.so  
//Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.  
//oca: 3 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]  
//ERROR: oca-1.2.7-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.  
//ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: ~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/oca/1.2.7-r0/temp/log.do_package.6146  
//ERROR: Task (~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland/meta-oca-so/recipes-example/oca/oca_1.2.7.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'  
//[Above text is all in red; back to white text following]  
//NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 504 tasks of which 2 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.  

//Summary: 1 task failed:  
  //~/Yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build-wayland/meta-oca-so/recipes-example/oca/oca_1.2.7.bb:do_package  
//Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.  

//real    19m43.796s  
//user    0m1.270s  
//sys     0m0.164s
```

It seems that not packaging the build result is not the answer.

Edit: An apparent can of worms has opened, necessitating a new question; please see [How do I get a complex non-Yocto makefile-based project to cross-compile in a Yocto layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680355/how-do-i-get-a-complex-non-yocto-makefile-based-project-to-cross-compile-in-a-yo)

Comment: using plain make within do_compile tasks seems wrong. would you mind to try to use oe_runmake ?

Comment: @Florian Berndl: Thanks for that input. I'll try it right away. The next error I'm getting is: "cc1plus: error: bad value ('armv8-a') for '-march=' switch" which got me to find out that I can't use the host machine's installed gcc for cross-compiling and I am trying to figure out how to set up the cross-compilation that is happening in my other added layers. Would changing to oe_runmake do it or are there additional changes necessary?

Comment: Changing the make in the do_compile to oe_runmake didn't make any apparent difference in doing "bitbake oca"; I'm still getting "cc1plus: error: bad value ('armv8-a') for '-march=' switch" I always delete the tmp folder and do "bitbake -c cleansstate oca" first.

Comment: An apparent can of worms has opened, necessitating a new question; please
see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680355/how-do-i-get-a-complex-non-yocto-makefile-based-project-to-cross-compile-in-a-yo

Answer (score 1):

The last error of you question tells you that the do_install tasks installs files but they are not assigned to any package.
Add following lines to your recipe

```
FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/OcaProtoController.so"
```

Comment: Thanks; that helps. It's going on to other errors now. I was kind of hoping for an answer that would obviate the horrible hack; see edited addition in my post that I'll add soon. I upvoted your answer.